# Override style in jquery.mobile-1.0b3.min.css

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I am building a mobile site using jquery.mobile-1.0b3.min.css.  If I download the css file, I lose some of the effects and icons from the theme I'm using.  But I need to override some styling in that file even though it's hosted at jquerymobile.com.

The style I need to override is ui-select.  The width attribute of this style is width: 60%, but I need to remove that style altogether while leaving the rest intact.

```
.ui-select {
width: 60%;
display: inline-block;
}
```

Is there a way to remove width: 60%; without effecting display: inline-block;?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your own stylesheet that overrides any previous styles. (Just make sure your custom stylesheet loads after the jQuery stylesheet.)

Comment: I can revise style elements that way, but i don't know how to remove the width style completely.  I need there to be no mention of width at all.

Comment: Override it and set to `width: auto;`

Comment: Thanks Kevin!  That did it.  I knew there was a simple answer but I couldn't think of it.